# adding new methods to LINQ to Entities

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is there any way to define the SQL conversion component for additional functions to Linq2Entities.

For example:

```
myQuery.Where(entity => entity.Contains('foo', SearchFlags.All))
```

Ideally I am looking for something that doesn't require editing and building a new version the EntityFramework.dll directly. Is there any way to allow extension methods to entity framework that can support SQL generation.

So far I have a template which would represent the method I need to replace for LINQ to Entities:

```
public static bool Contains(this object source, string searchTerms, SearchFlags flags)
{
    return true;
}
```

Of course this causes the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   CONTAINS(System.Object, System.String, SearchFlags)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.

To be clear, I don't want to do:

```
myQuery.AsEnumerable().Where(entity => entity.Contains('foo', SearchFlags.All))
```

Because I want to be able to execute code in SQL space and not return all the entities manually.

I also cannot use the `.ToString()` of the `IQueryable` and execute it manually because I need Entity Framework to populate the objects from several `.Include` joins.

Comment: "*Model-declared functions*" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382839.aspx) or "*Model-defined functions*" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382833.aspx) might be a way you could try. Both are not supported for Code-First, only EDMX-based workflows (DB-First or Model-First) and the latter one requires to use Entity SQL which does not have all SQL features.

Comment: @Slauma both look useful however I'm stuck with code-first, I might use them to argue we should be using DB-first since we manage the DB separate to EF anyway

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you running your code against?

Comment: I can use up to SQL Server 2012, so I could define it some CLR functions to do my code but I still can't call them using typed Linq `.Where(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following (which works but is very far from perfect):

1. All my entities inherit from an `IEntity` which defines `long Id { get; set; }`
2. I then added a redundant restriction
   `context.myEntities.Where(entity => entity.Id != 0)` this is
   redundant since the identity starts at 1, but Linq2Entities doesn't
   know that.
3. I then call `.ToString()` on the `IQueryable` after I have done all
   my other queries, since it is of type `DBQuery<Entity>` it returns
   the SQL Command Text, I do a simple replace with my query restriction.
4. In order to get all the `.Include(...)` to work I actually execute
   two different sql commands. There is no other more pretty way to tap into this because of query execution plan caching causes issues otherwise (even when disabled).

As a result my code looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<IEntity> MyNewFunction(IQueryable<IEntity> myQueryable, string queryRestriction)
{
    string rawSQL = myQueryable.Select(entity => entity.Id).ToString().Replace("[Extent1].Id <> 0", queryRestriction);
    List<long> ids = // now execute rawSQL, get the list of ids;
    return myQuerable.Where(entity => ids.Contains(entity.Id));
}
```

In short, other than manually executing the SQL or running a similar SQL command and appending the restriction using the existing commands the only way to write your own methods to Linq-to-Entities is to manually alter and build your own EntityFramework.dll from the EF6 source.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your Q clearly. However if your problem is that you can't use your own methods or other linq to objects method, just use `.AsEnumerable()` and do your other jobs through linq to objects, not L2E:

```
myQuery.AsEnumerable().Where(entity => entity.Contains('foo', SearchFlags.All))
```

And if you need to use your `myQuery` several times somewhere else, first load it to memory, then use it as many as you want:

```
var myQuery = from e in context.myEntities
              select d;
myQuery.Load();

// ...

var myOtherQuery = from d in context.myEntities.Local                        
                    select d;
                    // Now any L2O method is supported...
```

Comment: Does this recommendation make sense after he said in his question "*To be clear, I don't want to do... `AsEnumerable()`...*"?

Comment: @Slauma - I didn't see that. So he can use the second... Can't he...?! Am I wrong...?!!!

Comment: It's basically the same as `AsEnumerable` (load unfiltered data into memory). I think he just doesn't want to load a whole table (with perhaps million of records) into memory and filter there.